# EXCEL: I want to count how many times a certain word appears in a column if it's in the same row if another word appears

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to count how many times a certain word appears in a column if it's in the same row --- if another word appears in another column.

I am working with 2 sheets.

I want to get the information in the 1st sheet, while looking into the 2nd sheet.

Column G has either deployed or pending

Column J has Department names

I want to get the number of times it says Deployed if it falls in the same row of a particular department name

I tried Various Countifs, but unsuccessful.

One countifs I tried was:

=COUNTIFS('Full List'!G:G, "deployed",'Full List'!J:J,"Operations")

Full List is the sheet name
Operations is the department name

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Please post some sample data.

Comment: =COUNTIFS('Full List'!G:G, "deployed",'Full List'!J:J,"Operations")
As you say works perfectly for me, what seems to be the problem with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Sumproduct instead the formula will be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(G2:G14="Deployed")*(--(J2:J14="Operations")))
```

You can change G2:G14 and J2:J14 to your Data references but remember it should be the same number of rows in column G as column J in order to have a number result.

And use `--` to convert logical `True` to `1`.

When it is `True` in both column the formula will add `1` to the result.

With `COUNTIFS` the formula is working:

```
=COUNTIFS(G2:G14,"deployed",J2:J14,"operations")
```

It gives the same result, check the references and the data

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!G:G,"deployed",Sheet1!J:J,"operations")
```

[image]